# Getting the HTTP client's IP

Tags: php, http, ip-address

Can you please tell me whether this is a good way to get the user's IP (IPv4 or IPv6)? Does someone have a better way to do this? Please take a look at the entire code, the `server_params` order and the comments.

```
/* We are looking for ip in server params */
$server_params = array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'REMOTE_ADDR');

foreach($server_params as $server_param)
{
    /* If server param exists and his value is a real ip */
    if(isset($_SERVER[$server_param]) && filter_var($_SERVER[$server_param], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        /* If we are here, then means that the ip is whether IPV4 or IPV6 */
        /* This means that we can set user_ip as binary - We will insert this ip into an mysql column - VARBINARY (16) */
        define('user_ip',inet_pton($_SERVER[$server_param]));
        break;
    }
}

/* If the user_ip is not defined or the inet_pton failed (can inet_pton fail if is defined ?) */
if(!defined('user_ip') || user_ip === false) { echo 'Error. Your ip is not valid'; exit(); }
```

Comment: [Related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7623187/1157100)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would change :

- The answer to the question (see 200_success comment) states that the only thing that is hard to spoof is REMOTE_ADDR, so you should put this value first in your array.
- I'm not a big fan of your double test (*isset* and *filter_var*). I would like to trust that the implementation of *filter_var* is a good one and that it does test the emptyness of your variable before going any futher, but I'm not sure. Anyway, I'll just keep the test with *filter_var* .
- Not a big fan of your *define* either, why do you want to use a constant ? I would initialize a variable *userIP* before the *foreach* to *false*, so there's only one test to do after the loop.

One thing that worries me a bit is the existence of a case where *filter_var* would succeed but *inet_pton* would fail (for the same value). It should not exist, but if it does, you might exit your loop with *userIP* equal to *false*, while there is one valid IP in one of the following server variables. So just to be sure, I would add a test on *inet_pton* before breaking out of the loop.